# Content gets pushed under toolbar when using animateLayoutChanges="true"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I created a new Android Studio Project with the Navigation Drawer Activity.

Then I added a simple TextView inside a LinearLayout in the content_main.xml.
To this LinearLayout (also tried it with the standart RelativeLayout) I added the 
    `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`
parameter.

If I now toggle the visibility of the TextView between GONE and VISIBLE, the whole root LinearLayout of content_main.xml gets pushed up and is hidden under the toolbar.

here is my content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#84d8ff">

<TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="207dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0004"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <TextView android:text="Lorem Ipsum..."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test_item"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a picture:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axJs0.jpg)

The blue background belongs to the root LinearLayout of content_main.xml, the green background belongs to the app_bar_main.xml which includes the content_main.xml

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. This can be fixed by opening the layout app_bar_main.xml

You find the line:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Change it to this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is an ugly fix but it works for now.

If another issue raises, you can fix it by adding this as the direct child of the rootlayout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

</android.support.v4.widget.Space>
```